# relative layout gravity center not aligning correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, gravity

I'm trying to center the chilldren of my relative layout in the center of my screen but it's acting like it's aligned to the top of the parent and I can't figure out why.

my .XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#f70909">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/dice"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/textMessage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editUserSplash"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textMessage" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editPasswordSplash"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editUserSplash" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/btnSplash"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editPasswordSplash" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/prgSplash"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar.Large"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSplash" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried making the parent a `relativelayout` without success and it won't align to the bottom either. Initially I thought the layout wasn't filling the whole screen but since its height and width are `match_parent` I don't think that's the problem. in android studio it is displaying correctly though so I must be missing something small.

I also tried using the `gravity` and `layoutgravity` parameters and a combination of the two but without success

Edit:[image: screenshot] I need the views to stay in the same formation relative to each other but centered in the screen vertically.

Edit 2:I set the background of the `RelativeLayout` to red and got this:[image: red background] So the relativelayout isn't filling my screen.

Edit 3: [image: archi rayan]
Edit 4: [image: archi rayan]

Comment: use android:layout_centerInParent = "true"

Comment: you mean on the parent or the children?

Comment: what exactly do u want ??

Comment: Post your screen shot and explain what your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ank I was able to figure out that the reason why the RelativeLayout didn't fill my screen is that I used it in an alertDialog. So RelativeLayouts parent isn't the screen but the alertDialog. Since an alertDialog wraps its content it doesn't fill the entire screen.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f70909">

<RelativeLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/dice"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/textMessage"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editUserSplash"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textMessage" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editPasswordSplash"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editUserSplash" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/btnSplash"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editPasswordSplash" />

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/prgSplash"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar.Large"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnSplash" />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/imageView2"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

  <LinearLayout 
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:id="@+id/textMessage" />

      <EditText
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/editUserSplash"
          android:hint="Username"
          android:gravity="center" />

      <EditText
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/editPasswordSplash"
          android:hint="Password"
          android:gravity="center" />

      <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Login"
          android:id="@+id/btnSplash" />

      <ProgressBar
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/prgSplash"
          style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar.Large"
          android:indeterminate="true" />

  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

UPDATE:

If setting the xml in an AlertDialog, it's possible that there is a space allotted at the bottom. I google and found this [alert_dialog.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog.xml) for reference. It seems that there is a buttonPanel at the bottom with a minimum height of 54dip.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttonPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="54dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="4dip"
        android:paddingStart="2dip"
        android:paddingEnd="2dip"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="true">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/leftSpacer"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/rightSpacer"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: no luck the image is still aligned with the top of the screen

Comment: now the views are centered within the image so the relativelayout isn't filling my entire screen for some reason...

Comment: @ank This will `Overlap` the other views while image is in center.

Comment: might not be relevant but are you setting the xml in an activity or fragment?

Comment: it's actually in an alertDialog with `android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen` so the dialog is it's parent, not the screen... You're right I didn't think of that. guess I'll have to cheat a bit then. Could you edit your answer so i can accept it?

Comment: updated answer. also added a url reference to the alert_dialog.xml for reference.

Comment: I dont think it was the button bar I create the Dialog from my Splash xml i.e.
`final View dialogView = View.inflate(ThreeFragment.activity, R.layout.splash, null);
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ThreeFragment.activity, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen).create();` so the Dialog appeared fullscreen but was actually wrapping its content.

Answer (score 1):

```
I think this may help you

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">
    <RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textMessage"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editUserSplash"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textMessage"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editPasswordSplash"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editUserSplash"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/btnSplash"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editPasswordSplash"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Same problem when I do this the layout only becomes as large as the image. It's treating the outer layout as `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`

Comment: can you send me screenshot?

Comment: now just remove android:background="@drawable/dice" from layout. It will work

Comment: added screenshot the linearlayout just isn't matching its parent it's just wrapping its content

Comment: see i update my answer now check.and let me not it's right or not?

Comment: the problem was different since it was in an alertdialog which wraps its content the layout was filling it's parent but the parent was wrapping its content so the layout didn't fill my screen. I thought the parent was the screen but the actual parent is the alertdialog which wraps its content. Its something I learned to live with, I just added some padding so it looked somewhat better.